# Process a large list with delay

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, delay

One of the APIs expects a huge list as an input and I would like to partition into batches of, let's say 10, and I need to add delays in each batch processing.

For example:

```
List<SomeClass> hugeList = listFromRequest;
List<List<SomeClass>> listAfterPartition = new LinkedList<>(); // assuming that the partition is successful and each partition is size 10;
for (List<SomeClass> partition: listAfterPartition) {
    someService.callMethod(partition);
    Thread.sleep(60000);
}
```

I need to perform the same thing but without `Thread.sleep()`. I was looking at `ScheduledExecutorService` but couldn't figure out how to go about it. Also if its a new task using any other `ScheduledExecutorService`, how do I stop once all partitions are processed. Let me know please. (Can't use RxJava)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is a delay required?

Comment: I agree with @jon-hanson, why the need for a delay? Regardless, it looks like you are looking for a way of processing massive amounts of data in an efficient way. I would recommend you search for "Java Batch Processing", because your splitting up a large list into smaller units of work is exactly that batch processing is.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to process the list of lists concurrently then just use an `ExecutorService`, e.g.:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final List<List<String>> testData = new ArrayList<>();
    {
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
        l.add("A"); l.add("AA"); l.add("AAA");
        testData.add(l);
        l = new ArrayList<>();
        l.add("BB"); l.add("BBB"); l.add("BBBB"); l.add("BBBBB");
        testData.add(l);
        l = new ArrayList<>();
        l.add("CCC"); l.add("CCCC"); l.add("CCCCC"); l.add("CCCCCC"); l.add("CCCCCCC");
        testData.add(l);
    }

    final List<Integer> li = parallelProcess(
            testData,
            ls -> ls.stream().map(String::length).reduce(0, Integer::sum)
    );

    li.forEach(System.out::println);

    execSvc.shutdownNow();
}

private static final ExecutorService execSvc = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

private static <T, R> List<R> parallelProcess(List<List<T>> llt, Function<List<T>, R> processor) {

    final List<Future<R>> lfr =
            llt.stream()
                    .map(ll -> execSvc.submit(() -> processor.apply(ll)))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return lfr.stream()
            .map(f -> {
                try {
                    return f.get();
                } catch (ExecutionException|InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```